# Overloaded method and reflective calls

Tags: scala, reflection, structural-typing

In the following REPL session:

```
scala> new Object { def foo = "bar" }
res0: Object{def foo: String} = $anon$1@131a24c

scala> res0.foo
<console>:9: warning: reflective access of structural type member method foo should be enabled by making the implicit value language.reflectiveCalls visible.
          res0.foo
               ^
res1: String = bar

scala> trait Foo { def foo: String }
defined trait Foo

scala> new Foo { def foo = "bar"; def foo(bar: Int, baz: Int) = "bar" }
res2: Foo{def foo(bar: Int,baz: Int): String} = $anon$1@18a4aef

scala> res2.foo(1, 2)
res4: String = bar
```

the invocation to `res0.foo` is a reflective call, since `res0` has added a new structural member to `Object`. However, the invocation to `res2.foo(1, 2)` does not complain about the lack of `import language.reflectiveCalls`. Obviously `def foo: String` is causing that silent. Shouldn't `res2.foo(1, 2)` be a reflective call? Can somebody explain the reason why the compiler keeps quiet?

Comment: your question requires to know how method call resolution works internally. The declaration of foo in the trait let the runtime know that such a named class member exists, but all the members with the same name probably share the same slot in the class runtime representation, thus the runtime doesn't need to use the reflexion API to find the overloaded `foo`.